# Подсветка выбранного элемента меню при помощи Django в Templates не работает. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, backend, django-template

Прописал ифы, в которых сравнивается настоящий адрес страницы с адресом в заголовке. Однако иф не работает. Я проверял в обоих переменных одинаковые слова. Так же я пробовал вместо `request.get_full_path` вбивать руками адресс, но это тоже не работает. Подскажите что делать?

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
          {% for item in menu %}
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" {% if request.path == request.get_full_path %} class="active" {% endif %} aria-current="page" href="{% url item.url_name %}">{{ item.title }}</a>
              </li>
          {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Comment: один вопрос - зачем?

Comment: Чтобы было видно в каком разделе сайта ты находишься

Comment: зачем `{% if request.path == request.get_full_path %}`

Comment: используйте `item.url` или что там у вас

Comment: Всё так же, ничего не поменялось(

Comment: выведите и посмотрите что выводите, можете даже и нам показать